# XCode 4.5 Keeps using old code, despite updates

Tags: macos, debugging, xcode4.5

I have a several years old Mac project that I'm now doing maintenance using Xcode 4.5.  I made some changes to the code and was testing the changes using the debugger.  Every change I make is compiled as I see the relevant warnings and have had to fix errors along the way.  But when it actually runs, although it shows the code up to date, the debugger is behaving as though the prior version of code is still there.  It will line up with commented out code and execute that code as I step through.  Changes I have made are completely ignored, and it seems like the compiled code being debugged is the old code and not the new code that I am working with.

BUT, when I run the actual build file from my build subfolder, it does indeed have the changes in it.   Just can't debug it and need to in order to find an issue!

I am guessing that the derived data folder or the files that are used by the debugger are somehow out of sync or pointing to the wrong location.  I tried deleting everything there and of course have run multiple Clean's on the code, to no avail.  I've also tried switching between LLVM and GCC, and also the two debugger options in the edit scheme section.

Any ideas?

Comment: I right clicked the app icon on my dock and chose Show In Finder (under Options) and discovered that there are two different files being executed.  If debugging it gets the one in <project path>/build/Configuration Name  and if running the compiled project it's in <project path>/build/Build/Products/Configuration Name   My Build settings specify only the /build folder and none of the other subfolders.

Comment: I found a setting in the Xcode preferences for the build output and changed it to Legacy.  Now it uses the paths in the configuration file for both the debugger and the compiled output.  Not sure why Xcode would allow me to (and by default change to) having them in two different locations!